# Abrir URLs da DIST

Tags: angularjs, angular, electron

Estou tendo um problema de quando faço a build do projeto com o electron para chamar uma tela do UPDATE do projeto em Angular já que a dist do tem o index.html, no modo de desenvolvimento conseguido chamar tranquilho.

```
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:4200/#update');
```

no modo desenvolvimento consigo chamar dessa forma.

```
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
       pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html/#update'),
       protocol: 'file:',
       slashes: true
    }));
```

quando faço a build do projeto não consigo chamar a tela da o seguinte erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/dist/index.html#/update');
```

essa maneira consegui resolver o problema